# Detect exact event in multiple events over HTML element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to detect which event is triggered, like example below:

```
$("#some_element_id").on('blur keyup', function() {
     // if event is blur do something only for blur

     // do something for both events
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can inspect the `type` property of the event to determine which it was:

```js
$("#some_element_id").on('blur keyup', e => {
  if (e.type == 'blur') {
    console.log('the element lost focus');
  } else if (e.type === 'keyup') {
    console.log('a key was typed');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="some_element_id" />
```

As you can see this gets a little verbose and the logic becomes more difficult to follow. An alternative is to provide `on()` with an object whose keys are the event names you want to handle, and the values are the handler functions, like this:

```js
$("#some_element_id").on({
  blur: () => console.log('the element lost focus'),
  keyup: () => console.log('a key was typed')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="some_element_id" />
```

Answer (score 1):

With a little search on google, you have `event.type`

https://api.jquery.com/event.type/

Answer (score 0):

I would seperate them:

```
$("#some_element_id")
  .on('blur', function() {
       // Do something only for blur
       doTheBothThing();
  })
  .on('keyup', function() {
       // Do something only for keyup
       doTheBothThing();
  });
```

Technically you can check the event.type, but I would seperate the flows for a more solid design